# running parallel npm scripts on windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json, npm-scripts

I have an npm parallel script in my package.json that works on a mac but not on windows:

```
"myScript": "nodemon ./server.js & cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server"
```

When it is separated into two scripts to run separately, it works fine on both mac and windows:

```
"myScript1": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server",
"myScript2": "nodemon ./server.js",
```

I would like to keep the parallel script so that I don't have to run both separately.  How do I make this work on windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a workaround for this, using module [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently). So you script section would look something like this:

```
scripts: {
  "myScript": "concurrently \"npm run myScript1\" \"npm run myScript2\"",
  "myScript1": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server",
  "myScript2": "nodemon ./server.js",
}
```

Comment: yeah that's what I ended up using.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [npm-run-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all)
I think the syntax is a bit cleaner:

```sh
scripts: {
  "myScript": "run-p myScript1 myScript2",
  "myScript1": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server",
  "myScript2": "nodemon ./server.js",
}
```

This npm-run-all package provides 3 CLI commands.

- npm-run-all
- run-s
- run-p

The main command is npm-run-all. We can make complex plans with npm-run-all command.

Both run-s and run-p are shorthand commands.
run-s is for sequential, run-p is for parallel. We can make simple plans with those commands.